# Why is sidekiq running at the minute I specify, but not the hour?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq

I'm using Rails 5.  I don't understand why my Sidekiq worker doesn't run when scheduled on my local machine.  I have set up this config/sidekiq.yml ...

```
---
:concurrency: 5
:verbose: true
:logfile: ./log/sidekiq.log
:queues:
  - default
:schedule:
  Accounting::Workers::AuditWorker:
    cron: "35 15 * * *"
    queue: default
```

I start things up running

```
bundle exec sidekiq -C ./config/sidekiq.yml
```

but at the specified time (3:35 PM), nothing happens.  When I change the expression to

```
cron: "35 * * * *"
```

Then I see output from my worker at exactly 35 past the hour.  Worker looks like ...

```
require 'sidekiq/api'

module Accounting::Workers
  class AuditWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker

    def perform
      print "Beginning service #{Time.now}...\n"
        ...
    end
```

What else do I need to do to get things to run at the time I specify?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way**

```
cron: '35 20 * * *'
```

Worked for me putting it in **UTC**